# Get a Paypal report automatically each month

Tags: paypal

Instead of each week / each month having to log in, go to either the new interface (that I find less handy to export data) or the [old interface "Download History"](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_history-download):

[image]

then choose dates, select format (e.g. `Tab delimited - Completed payments`), click export, etc. **is it possible to have a report sent automatically by Paypal each month?** (e.g. via email)

Comment: You can set up Paypal IPN which will log all transactions on your server. And then if you want an email report you can use your own mail servers to send it. It's not easy to setup but it may be worth it for you if you're making revenue this way.

Comment: @Michaeld I already use IPN (via PHP) to send emails to the customers, etc. But having the report directly sent from Paypal would be more precise (in case of refunds, etc.), of other transactions (purchases) that don't trigger IPN, etc.

Comment: To the downvoter: could you leave a comment to explain how to improve the question?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I'm ok to do it with my own website, self-hosted (as I said, I already use IPN), as long as we can have a full report (refunds, other transactions like purchases, etc.). This is definitely a question that arises for "ProWebmasters" in the management of their website. Do you think it could be possible to reopen it?